# nVidia GPU returns-1000 for clEnqueueWriteImage

Tags: opengl, opencl, nvidia

Tying to figure out what the issue (and error code) is for this call. First to preface this works just fine on AMD, it only has issues on nVidia.

```
unsigned char *buffer;
...
cl_int status;
cl::size_t<3> origin;
cl::size_t<3> region;

origin[0]=0;
origin[1]=0;
origin[2]=0;

region[0]=m_width;
region[1]=m_height;
region[2]=1;

status=clEnqueueWriteImage(m_commandQueue, m_image, CL_FALSE, origin, region, 0, 0, buffer, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

status returns -1000, which is not a standard openCl error code. All other functions related to the opening of the device, context, and command queue all succeed. The context is interop'ed with openGl and again this is all completely functional on AMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, seems the error happens if the image is interop'ed with an OpenGL texture and the call is made before the image is acquired using clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects. I had used the acquire later when images were used but not right before the image was set. Amd's driver does not appear to care about this little detail.